# Like a Facebook page in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like, request

I need to create a button that likes a certain website. It should look like [that](http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.apple.com/&send=false&layout=button_count&width=450&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=21)
I read a lot and most people say it cannot be done. I tried to put this url in a webView, but there seem to be no way I can add the Facebook user Token so that the client doesn't need to log in but just click it. Is there anyway this can be done?

Here is the url request:

```
 http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.apple.com%2F&send=false&layout=button_count&width=450&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=21
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pull in the [Facebook iOS SDK from Github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/) to your project and [set it up using Facebook's instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/), you will be able to get the exact functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Another option is one of the sharing frameworks, such as FTShare: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ftshare-an-easy-way-to-share-using-facebook-twitter-and-mails. This will let you share with other networks such as twitter. Another popular one is sharekit: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit

Comment: I read a lot and I understood I need a OpenGraph object to send the like request, yet It says that I need to add some meta tags to my web page. I need to like a facebook page, not a web page. Here, it is show the http post request https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/
but it needs a open graph object url, which i suppose is no just the facebook page link